# sending data to a modal form in jsp page using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, scriptlet

I have a problem sending and receiving data from a button to a modal form in bootstrap.

Inside my button tag I have:

```
data-comment=<%=Comentarios.listUltimos().get(i).getComentario() %>
```

And then I take that data with a java script code in the event on click, where I fill the form.

```
var myComentario = $(this).data('comment');
document.getElementById("myModalComment").value=myComentario;
```

It works fine but It only takes the first word of the content I have in my Database.

Comment: Try to use data-comment="<%=Comentarios.listUltimos().get(i).getComentario()%>" if not between the quotes it is normal that only first word is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're inserting the data as-is without proper quoting:

```
<sometag attr=foo bar baz>
```

Which parses into a tag with attributes:

```
attr="foo"
bar
baz
```

When what you really meant was:

```
<sometag attr="foo bar baz">
```

What you want to do is surround the `<%...%>` with quotes and proper escaping:

```
data-comment="<%=Comentarios.listUltimos().get(i).getComentario().replace("\"", "\\\"") %>"
```